# The correct usage of commas when writing about your location

Tags: commas

> I live in London, England but we can work....
>
> I live in London, England, but we can work....

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: To quote the advice given on a similar question (which unfortunately I can no longer find a link for as I can't remember the exact wording of it) say the sentence aloud to yourself. If you paused, use a comma. If you didn't, don't. In this case I'd probably recommend the latter phrasing since if I were saying that to someone I'd pause after England to make it clear that what follows is a separate clause.

Comment: Your question title reads like you are asking about a comma after "London" and your sentences read like you are asking about it before "but". What is your question? Did you do your own research to find an answer? Remember we are not a proof-reading service site. You need to be more specific on your question with your own research. Placing a comma is easily searchable on the internet.

Comment: @Rathony : I love your : "we are not a proof-reading service site !"

Comment: Duplicate (essentially) of [Should i put a comma after a state before a country](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312239/should-i-put-a-comma-after-a-state-before-a-country)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp) says we use a comma to separate a city from its state and use one after the state as well (Rule #10). Accordingly, write

> I live in London, England, but we can work ...